# UTF-8 string array using graphemes vs split

Tags: arrays, string, utf-8, julia

Is there an advantage to using `graphemes` over `split` for creating an array from a UTF-8 string?

For example, consider the following:

```julia
# Define a UTF-8 string with a bunch of multibyte characters
s = "{(-n↑⍵÷⊃⊖⍵),⍨⍉1↓⍉∘.=⍨⍳n←1-⍨≢⍵}"

# Create an array using split
split(s, "")

# Create an array using graphemes (v0.4+)
collect(graphemes(s))
```

Both approaches produce the expected output. And indeed,

```julia
split(s, "") == collect(graphemes(s))
```

returns `true`.

The two approaches seem to consistently produce equivalent results. Is one approach generally preferred over another, be it for performance, style, or otherwise?

(Note that `graphemes` returns an iterator rather than an array, hence the `collect`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on what you are looking for.  `graphemes()` will return what users would perceive as single characters, even though they may contain more than one codepoint; for example a letter combined with an accent mark is a single grapheme.  This is not the case with `split()`.

Consider a + ◌́ .  In this example, `split()` will return the two codepoints as separate characters whereas `graphemes()` will return a single character.